# How to vary plot axis by user input (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny and learning it's features.  Using the mtcars data, I am trying to create a plot whose axis will alter upon user input.  When I run the app, I am getting error telling me the "x and y lengths are not the same", so it appears that "data" specified in the plot function is not receiving the mtcars dataframe columns.  The plot works property if I replace "data" with any of the columns listed in the server function.

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1"),
  tabPanel("Component 2"),
  tabPanel("Component 3",
    fluidPage(                      
      fluidRow(       
        column(4,
          "Sidebar",
          helpText("This is my longer help text help text."),
          selectInput("var",
            label = "Choose a variable to display",
            choices = c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "qsec"),
            selected = "A")  
        ),
        column(8,
          #style = "background-color:#4d3a7d;",
          "Main",
          textOutput("selected_var"),
          plotOutput("plot1")
        )
      )
    )
),
  navbarMenu("More",
    tabPanel("Sub-Component A"),
    tabPanel("Sub-Component B"))
))


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    if("mpg" %in% input$var) return(mtcars$mpg)
    if("disp" %in% input$var) return(mtcars$disp)
    if("hp" %in% input$var) return(mtcars$hp)
    if("qsec" %in% input$var) return(mtcars$qsec)
  })

  output$selected_var <- renderText({
    paste("you have selected", input$var)
  }) 

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, data)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - "data" should have been "data()".

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `switch` instead of `if`.  Also, in the `selected` in `selectInput`, it could be one of the `choices`.  Not sure where `"A"` is defined

```
library(shiny)
```

-ui

```
ui <- navbarPage("My Application",
                   tabPanel("Component 1"),
                   tabPanel("Component 2"),
                   tabPanel("Component 3",
                            fluidPage(                      
                              fluidRow(       
                                column(4,
                                       "Sidebar",
                                       helpText("This is my longer help text help text."),
                                       selectInput("var",
                                                   label = "Choose a variable to display",
                                                   choices = c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "qsec"),
                                                   selected = "mpg")  
                                ),
                                column(8,
                                       #style = "background-color:#4d3a7d;",
                                       "Main",
                                       textOutput("selected_var"),
                                       plotOutput("plot1")
                                )
                              )
                            )
                   ),
                   navbarMenu("More",
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component A"),
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component B"))
)
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
     switch(input$var,
            mpg = mtcars$mpg,
            dist = mtcars$disp,
            hp = mtcars$hp,
            qsec = mtcars$qsec
            )

  })

  output$selected_var <- renderText({
    paste("you have selected", input$var)
  }) 

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, data(), xlab = "wt", ylab = input$var)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]